# How Do I Parse a Date in Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, date, time

Right Now I am trying to parse the values from my get time and date and break it down by each number

Format of the date/time

```
#!/bin/bash 
prevDateTime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
echo "${prevDateTime}"
```

I want to be able to list it out like so

```
echo "${prevYear}"
echo "${prevMonth}"
echo "${prevDay}"
echo "${prevHour}"
echo "${prevMinute}"
echo "${prevSecond}"
```

and then like

```
echo "${prevDate}"
echo "${precTime}"
```

But I am not sure how to parse out the information any help would be great

Comment: Like `prevYear=$(date +'%Y')` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution using cut:

```
#!/bin/bash 
prevDateTime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
echo "${prevDateTime}"

prevYear=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f1`
prevMonth=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f2`
prevDay=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f3`
prevHour=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f4 | cut -d: -f1`
prevMinute=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f4 | cut -d: -f2`
prevSecond=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f4 | cut -d: -f3`

echo "Year: $prevYear; Month: $prevMonth; Day: $prevDay"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
echo "Hour: $prevHour; Minute: $prevMinute; Second: $prevSecond"
```

Comment: Worked like a dream just wondering if there is a way to spilt it and have date as a single variable instead of 3 separate ones ??

Comment: Same thing, use: fullData=`echo $prevDateTime | cut -d- -f1,2,3`
echo "Date: $fullData"

Comment: Using `cut` like this is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @chepner, sure it was fast solution, yours is even better

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression is probably the simplest solution, given the format of `prevDateTime`.

```
[[ $prevDateTime =~ (.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*):(.*):(.*) ]]
prevYear=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
prevMonth=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
# etc.
```

Technically, there's a "one"-liner to do this using `declare`:

```
declare $(date +'prevDateTime=%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S
prevYear=%Y
prevMonth=%m
prevDat=%d
prevHour=%H
prevMinute=%M
prevSecond=%S')
```

It uses `date` to output a block of parameter assignments which `declare` instantiates. (Note that the command substitution is not quoted, so that each assignment is seen as a separate argument to `declare`. If there was any whitespace in the values to assign, you would have to switch to using `eval` with slightly different output from `date`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read` command with `IFS` to break down date components:

```
prevDateTime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
IFS='-:' read -ra arr <<< "$prevDateTime"

# print array values
declare -p arr
# This outputs
#   declare -a arr='([0]="2015" [1]="05" [2]="21" [3]="10" [4]="24" [5]="28")'

#assign to other variables
prevYear=${arr[0]}
prevMonth=${arr[1]}
prevDay=${arr[2]}
prevHour=${arr[3]}
prevMinute=${arr[4]}
prevSecond=${arr[5]}
```

Comment: The `[]` aren't necessary in the value of `IFS`. (They're just additional unused field delimiters.)

Comment: It does, sort of. The entire value is treated implicitly as a character class, so for splitting `IFS=-:` and `IFS=:-` would be equivalent. (The exception is for uses of `IFS` to join words into a single string, where only the first character is used, so then order is important.)